# Excel VBA: changing column order of raw data sheet affects every other sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I’ve been working on a workbook where I’m importing raw data sheets and there are references all over the workbook to the columns in these sheets.
An issue I’ve encountered is that sometimes the columns aren’t in the right place, and so I’ve been using a script to reorder the columns, primarily so I can use VLOOKUPS throughout the workbook instead of INDEX/MATCH. Here is the code I’ve been using to reorder the columns, which I found on here somewhere:

```
Sub reOrder_Metadata_Columns()

'Running this script will put the columns in the Metadata table in the order specified
'This is important because now we can use VLOOKUP to get the proper column


Dim arrColOrder As Variant, Ndx As Integer
Dim found As range, counter As Integer

'This is the correct order of the columns:
arrColOrder = Array("Field1", " Field2", "Field3", "Field4", "Field5”)


counter = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)

    Set found = Sheets("Metadata").Rows("1:1").Find(arrColOrder(Ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        If found.Column <> counter Then
            found.EntireColumn.Cut
            Sheets(“Metadata").Columns(counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    End If

Next Ndx

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It was working fine until today, when for some reason all the references in the other sheets in the same workbook are looking in the column where, for example, Field1 used to be, which may now be column 2.
How do I keep the rest of the workbook from changing when I change the order of columns in the raw data file? I tried using an absolute reference, for example, on a different page:

```
 =Metadata!$A1
```

and copied it all down the column, but it still changes when I reorder the Metadata table.

Comment: You could get the column index values from the header names and base all your code off of that, though you will run into the same issue as before if the names change.

Comment: Yeah I could have used INDEX/MATCH and done it that way but I made this gigantic workbook using VLOOKUP because I thought it wouldn't matter as long as I could put the columns in the right place before I looked for anything. What I don't understand is I do this exact procedure on a different raw data table (including adding a column) and it doesn't affect the references in the worksheet. I wonder why